# Azure SQL databases Audit/management

Tags: sql-server, azure, admin, cost-management

We have a number of Azure SQL databases and  we need to get a handle on what the size and cost  of each database is and if they are growing /shrinking in size , plus any other relevant information . I fear that we may lose control and the costs of these databases gets out of control.

Is there a way we can get this information from Azure by running some type of Audit Admin tool that can generate a report? Or is this something that I would need to run manually?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use azure [cost management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/cost-management-billing-overview). Cost Management shows organizational cost and usage patterns with advanced analytics. Reports in Cost Management show the usage-based costs consumed by Azure services and third-party Marketplace offerings.
You can use the Azure portal or various APIs for export automation to integrate cost data with external systems and processes. Automated billing data export and scheduled reports are also available.

Azure Cost Management has an alert feature. Alerts are generated when consumption reaches a threshold.
Consider the metrics that each resource in the workload. For each metric, build alerts on baseline thresholds. This way, the admins can be alerted when the workload is using the services at capacity. The admins can then tune the resources to target SKUs based on current load.

Please refer [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/azure-sql-database/single/) to understand sql database pricing models.

You may use azure [Pricing Calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/calculator/) as well